# Perform continuous animation with GLFW

Tags: opengl, glut, glfw

I want to use OpenGL to implement an animation that can be started and paused with mouse clicks. Since I am currently using the GLFW, the functions in GLUT are no longer applicable.

In GLUT, the implementation can be like this:

```
void windowMouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        // start
        glutIdleFunc(idleFunction);
    }
    else if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN) {
        // pause
        glutIdleFunc(NULL);
    }
}
```

However, `glutIdleFunc()` does not work in GLFW. I just wrote a coding frame to perform my goal but got stuck in finding the proper function to replace `glutIdleFunc()`.

```
void mouse_button_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mode)
{
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        // start
    }
    else if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        // pause
    }
}
```

Is there any function in GLFW that can replace the previous one? Or is there any way to perform continuous animation with GLFW?

Comment: Have you seen [Putting it together](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/quick.html#quick_example)?  The basic flow of a glfw program is a `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get creative with `glfwPostEmptyEvent()` and `glfwWaitEventsTimeout()`:

```
// g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs glfw3 gl`
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

void (*idleFunc)(GLFWwindow*) = nullptr;

void idle( GLFWwindow* aWindow )
{
    static float angle = 0.0f;
    static double prvTime = glfwGetTime();
    const double curTime = glfwGetTime();
    const double dt = (curTime - prvTime);
    prvTime = curTime;

    angle += 60.0 * dt;

    int w, h;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize( aWindow, &w, &h );
    glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef( angle, 0, 0, 1 );
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub( 0, 255, 0 );
    glVertex2f( -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.0,  0.5 );
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glfwSwapBuffers( aWindow );
}

void display( GLFWwindow* aWindow )
{
    int w, h;
    glfwGetFramebufferSize( aWindow, &w, &h );
    glViewport( 0, 0, w, h );
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glColor3ub( 255, 0, 0 );
    glVertex2f( -0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.5, -0.5 );
    glVertex2f(  0.0,  0.5 );
    glEnd();

    glfwSwapBuffers( aWindow );
}

void button( GLFWwindow* window, int button, int action, int mode )
{
    if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_LEFT && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        idleFunc = idle;
        glfwPostEmptyEvent();
    }
    else if (button == GLFW_MOUSE_BUTTON_RIGHT && action == GLFW_PRESS)
    {
        idleFunc = nullptr;
        glfwPostEmptyEvent();
    }
}

int main( int, char** )
{
    glfwInit();
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow( 640, 480, "GLFW", NULL, NULL );
    glfwMakeContextCurrent( window );

    glfwSetMouseButtonCallback( window, button );

    while( !glfwWindowShouldClose( window ) )
    {
        if(idleFunc)
        {
            idleFunc(window);
            glfwWaitEventsTimeout(0.016);
        }
        else
        {
            display(window);
            glfwWaitEvents();
        }
    }

    glfwTerminate();
}
```

The `glfwPostEmptyEvent()` along with the structure of the `glfwWindowShouldClose()` loop in `main()` lets you simulate the behavior of `glutPostRedisplay()` and the `glfwWaitEventsTimeout()` lets the `idleFunc()` (if any) run every 16 milliseconds or so.